# How to pass an HTML element ID to the function written in JavaScript and what's the error 'ele.offset is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, parameter-passing

I've a function written in JavaScript as follows :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function scrollToElement(ele) { //alert(ele);
  $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
}
</script>
```

And following is the call to the function :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var query_event_id = getParameterByName('event_id');
  var ele = document.getElementById('event_'+query_event_id);

  //scrollToElement($('#event_'+query_event_id));
  scrollToElement(ele);    
});
</script>
```

I'm facing following issues :

When I tried the code `scrollToElement($('#event_'+query_event_id));` and `alert(ele);`(inside function scrollToElemen()) I got `[Object object]` in alert.

When I tried the code `var ele = document.getElementById('event_'+query_event_id); scrollToElement(ele);` and `alert(ele);`(inside function scrollToElemen()) I got `null` in alert.

Why so? And how should I pass the id of an HTML element to the function then?

Then I tried passing the hard coded-value of id of a `<div>` which is present in HTML code as follows :

```
scrollToElement('event_512');
```

Then the alert shown me the proper element as `event_512` but in console I received following error.

```
TypeError: ele.offset is not a function


$(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
```

Now I become clueless of what should I do?

Can some one please help me in resolving my issue?

Thanks.

Comment: try `$(ele)` instead of `ele`.

Comment: Have you included jquery in your page? This is needed to support .offset ()

Comment: It means that you don't have element with such id on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery and non-jQuery functions here, which is rarely a good idea. Stick to one - for example use jQuery:

```
function scrollToElement( ele ) {
  $(window).scrollTop( ele.offset().top ).scrollLeft( ele.offset().left );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var query_event_id = getParameterByName('event_id');
  scrollToElement($('#event_'+query_event_id)); 
});
```

The alert with `[Object object]` is because JS converts the parameter of `alert()` to a string and the string representation of a jQuery object is `[Object object]`.

When you just use

```
var ele = document.getElementById('event_'+query_event_id);
```

to pass the parameter, you pass a DOM-element. The native DOM-element does not have a method called `offset()` (this is a jQuery method!), hence the error you receive there.

Comment: Sriko can we chat in a chat  room please? I tried your code but same is the result so it would be better if we chat and solve the issue.

Comment: @user2839497 Sure we can. I started a room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99584/

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass your element to jQuery before using jQuery functions.

you need to do it following manner:

```
$(ele).offset().top();
```

Now you are passing `ele` to jQuery, thus you can you use `offset()`.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.